# Sync Google, Outlook Calendar and Contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, google-calendar, google-contacts

At work we are on an exchange server, and at home I like to use Google calendar.

Whats the best way to keep my contacts and calendar in sync?

Comment: Did you get this to work for contact as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I run [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955) on my machine at work which has worked great!

Comment: Note: to install on XP64, you need to install in compatability mode. Right click the installer, select Compatibility, check Run this program in compatibility mode for: Windows XP.

Comment: Note that this is discontinued as of Dec 14th 2012.

[Official Google notice](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98565)

Answer (score 3):

Google has some apps that will keep Outlook and GCal in sync, also check the following out for some help. [Google Calendar Help](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955)