# is there any tool that sync between outlook and google calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sync Google, Outlook Calendar and Contacts](https://superuser.com/questions/2682/sync-google-outlook-calendar-and-contacts)

hi

is there any tool that sync between outlook 2007  and google calendar ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955). It will only sync your primary Google calendar with Outlook.