# Sync ALL Outlook Invites with Google Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar, google-calendar

Just to preface, this is not a duplicate of : 
[Sync Google, Outlook Calendar and Contacts](https://superuser.com/questions/2682/sync-google-outlook-calendar-and-contacts)

Is there any way to sync an **Outlook Calendar** with your **Google Calendar**, outside of 'Google Calendar Sync'?

'Google Calendar Sync' works but, only it syncs events on my calendar where I am the only invite.  Any group meetings I am invited to, do not show up.  I have search for a solution to this issue but, haven't found anything promising (or free).

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Google Calendat Sync includes group meetings for me. What 'Syne Option' do you have set? I have 1-way MS Outlook to Google.

Comment: @BradPatton That's what I have as well.  One pattern that I seem to notice is that on the events that are not showing up, the invite was sent to one of the Distribution Lists I am on.