# Is there a way to sync an Outlook calendar with Outlook.com?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar, outlook.com

I would like to be able to push my work calendar items up to an Outlook.com account. There are several questions (like [Sync Google, Outlook Calendar and Contacts](https://superuser.com/questions/2682/sync-google-outlook-calendar-and-contacts)) that reference a Google calendar and recommend the use the deprecated Google sync but I am looking to sync to Outlook.com.

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty easy to do.
I use EVO Collaborator for Outlook myself to sync Outlook.com to my Outlook (as well as other services) And I sync contacts,calendar and mails.

You can try it out and see if it works for you :)

A blogpost on syncing Outlook and Outlook.com here :
http://outlookandmacosxserver.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-sync-windows-live-hotmail.html

Comment: All of the explanation of how to accomplish the solution is in the link.  Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase rather than a collection of links to answers elsewhere.  External links can break, in which case your answer would have no value.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial [Sync calendar and contacts using Outlook.com](http://slipstick.com/outlook/olc-hotmail/sync-calendar-contacts-using-outlook-com/) shows step by step how to sync Outlook to Outlook.com. From first glance it will appear that it is pulling information from Outlook.com into Outlook but you will discover that it is indeed "pushing" up to Outlook.com.

Comment: I read through that one before and it looked like it was for syncing hotmail to outlook not the other way around. I will give it another read. Also it's encouraged that answers contain the relvant infomration and not just "link" to it.

Comment: I have corrected my answer.